# Exception: The starting row of the range is too small, but code doesnt work regardless of error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets, one with 13 columns (sheet 1) and one with 4 columns (sheet 2). I am trying to loop through the two sheets in google app script, compare their values in the first 3  columns and then copy over the values from the 4th column in sheet 2 to the 13th column in sheet 1.  Not only does the function not work, but I keep encountering the error: Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.

```
function labelRows() {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //store spreadsheet
    const sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // getSheets() returns an array of sheets
    const sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // getSheets() returns an array of sheets
    var data1_values = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
    var data2_values = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (n in data1_values) {
      for (m in data2_values) {
        var vowel1 = data1_values[n][1]; //get name vowel column 
        var speaker1 = data1_values[n][0]; //get speaker column 
        var word1 = data1_values[n][2]; //get word column 
        var vowel2 = data2_values[m][1]; //get name vowel column 
        var speaker2 = data2_values[m][0]; //get speaker column 
        var word2 = data2_values[m][2]; //get word column 
        var durations = data2_values[m][3];
        if ((vowel1 == vowel2) && (speaker1 == speaker2) && (word1 == word2)) {
          var durationsclass = sheet1.getRange(n,13);
          durationsclass.setValue(durations);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.  The start row of the range is too small.  So go into the editor and run the code in debug mode to find out where n is getting to be less than one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in your script, the initial value of `n` of `for (n in data1_values) {,,,}` is `0` of a string value. By this, such an error occurs at `var durationsclass = sheet1.getRange(n,13);`. Because `getRange` cannot use row 0. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When your showing script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var durationsclass = sheet1.getRange(n,13);
```

#### To:

```
var durationsclass = sheet1.getRange(Number(n) + 1, 13);
```

But, in this case, `setValue` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) So, as one more modified script, how about the following modification?

```js
function labelRows() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //store spreadsheet
  const sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // getSheets() returns an array of sheets
  const sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // getSheets() returns an array of sheets
  var data1_values = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data2_values = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

  // I modified the below script.
  var obj = data2_values.reduce((o, r) => (o[r.splice(0, 3).join("")] = r[0], o), {});
  var values = data1_values.map(r => [obj[r.splice(0, 3).join("")] || r[12]]);
  sheet1.getRange(1, 13, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)